# How to customize QTableWidget through stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtgui

I'm trying to customize a `QTableWidget` through stylesheet and I'm only limited to the items descibed [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview).

How do I change the spacing in the horizontal header of the table, the size of its header label, the spaces between the columns, et al?

Comment: You should try this link [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview)

Answer (score -1):

You should use [QAbstractItemDelegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractitemdelegate.html)  to control display of items in QTableWidget.

From explanation of [delegates](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes):

> "Unlike the Model-View-Controller pattern, the model/view design does not include a completely separate component for managing interaction with the user. Generally, the view is responsible for the presentation of model data to the user, and for processing user input. To allow some flexibility in the way this input is obtained, the interaction is performed by **delegates**. These components provide input capabilities and are also responsible for **rendering individual items** in some views. The standard interface for controlling delegates is defined in the **QAbstractItemDelegate** class."

From [QTableWidget::setItemDelegate()](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate):

> "Sets the item delegate for this view and its model to delegate. This is useful if you want complete control over the editing and **display** of items."

And for an example : [pixelator](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/itemviews-pixelator.html).

Comment: I'm actually looking for stylesheet options... :(

Comment: The person is looking for a solution using stylesheet and you are suggesting him delegates!! Are you serious?? : |

Comment: Ah sorry.. I must have confused somehow