# Excel grid -- class in Qt

Tags: excel, qt

I am making a tool on Qt which is capable of receiving messages from CAN bus. Now I need to show  these messages onto the Excel-like grid.

[image: Example]

Please suggest which class of Qt can be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would take [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html)/[QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html).

You can use Qt style sheets for customizing this widget: [How to customize QTableWidget through stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418304/how-to-customize-qtablewidget-through-qt-stylesheet)

Comment: Please mention that the actual widget that uses this model/view implementation is the `QTableWidget`.